# Are terminals alkyne reduced by Na/liq NH3?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

By the mechanism, it appears that any alkyne should be reduced, but I couldn't find any source supporting or disapproving it. One possibility is that first acid-base rxn takes place but still the reduction should happen.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this source  [here](https://www.saplinglearning.com/media/loudon/loudon5ech14sec06.pdf)

> The Na /NH3 reduction of alkynes does not work well on 1-alkynes unless certain modifications are made in the reaction conditions.

edit: Thanks to @Buttonwood for providing details on the modifications required. Addition of ammonium sulfate to the reaction mixture gives quantitative yields of alkene according to this edition of Modern Methods of Organic Synthesis [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mc3SCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=Terminal%20alkyne%20reduction%20with%20sodium%20ammonia%20ammonium%20%22sulfate%22&source=bl&ots=MgvRrXRIJK&sig=ACfU3U0mqUhBKHgyRZrRw-5yJTKAfG8U3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWzdCchrHzAhVDiFwKHf3tBm0Q6AF6BAgbEAM#v=onepage&q=Terminal%20alkyne%20reduction%20with%20sodium%20ammonia%20ammonium%20%22sulfate%22&f=false)

Comment: can you share problem 14.39 also of the above-mentioned source?

Comment: @Govind It possibly is a typo since problem 14.39 is about subsequent complications to have both ethynylmagnesium bromide and EtMgBr in one flask which may lead to double deprotonation and metallation (thus, «simply» a story of $pK_a$). And $\ce{NaNH2}$ equally is a base strong enough to deprotonate a terminal alkyne. Problem 14.40 of the same source however states the hassle of $\ce{3 RC#CH -> RCH=CH2 + 2RC#C^- + 2Na^+}$ with $\ce{Na/NH3}$ may be prevented by the addition of $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ to the reaction mixture.